# CONCAT_WS in custom sql query

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I'm trying to run a custom sql query against the WordPress `wp_postsmeta` table.
However, I can't seem to get `CONCAT_WS` to work as it did when I ran the query in the MySQL command line.

Right now I'm just trying to get `CONCAT_WS` to work. This is the relevant code:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.post_id, CONCAT_WS(',', $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value) from $wpdb->postmeta;";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
```

This is `$query` from the end of `var_dump`: `[...] 'SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, CONCAT_WS(',', wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value) from wp_postmeta' (length=105)`

This is what is returned:

```
0 => 
  object(stdClass)[2912]
    public 'post_id' => string '2' (length=1)
    public 'CONCAT_WS(',', wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value)' => string '_wp_page_template,default' (length=25)
```

Seems like it returns part of the query in the result.

Is `CONCAT_WS` not possible to use with WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

`'CONCAT_WS(',', wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value)'` was the name of the column. Everything is working as it should.

To change the name of the column, add `AS name` after the `CONCAT_WS` statement, like this:

`'CONCAT_WS(',', wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value)' AS name` (I didn't test this specifically).

Now the new column will be called `name`.